# Unable to install Eclipse IDE on my Mac

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to download Eclipse IDE for Android development. I've downloaded the setup but whenever I try to open the dmg it gives the an error saying:

"Can't open the application Eclipse because it is not supported on this type of Mac."

The Processor of my Mac is 1.83 GHz Intel Core Duo and version of my Mac OS X is 10.6.4.

I downloaded "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers"  4m  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Anyone have the idea about the problem?

Comment: Just completed my answer with new elements, thank to [zvikico](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2823/zvikico).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to set up "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" on my 32bit Mac and continuously failing in fixing it up for couple of days. I finally installed 32bit version of "Eclipse Classic 3.6.0" and Yeah it worked.

Thanx again VonC for all your time and support! =)

Comment: Yes! Glad to hear you manage to make it work. You are welcome ;)

Answer (score 4):

Did you install a 64-bit version of Eclipse like in [this thread](http://www.mydellmini.com/forum/general-mac-os-x-discussion/19944-not-supported-type-mac.html)?
If so, try a 32-bit instead.

The [snowleopard.wikidot](http://snowleopard.wikidot.com/) mentions Eclipse 3.5 being compatible, although:

> May require installing Java 1.5 since SL actually only ships with Java 1.6

---

Regarding your configuration, [**zvikico**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823/zvikico) adds in the comments:

> AFAIK, **the Core Duo is a 32 bit processor, not capable of running 64 bit at all.
>
>   Even if you install Snow Leopard.**
>   First, you need the 32 bit version. Second, make sure 32 bit Java is your default. You can set it using an application called JavaPreferences, sitting in the /Applications/Utilities.

So:

- check your Java and
- download the **[Macosx Cocoa 32bits](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/R/eclipse-java-helios-macosx-cocoa.tar.gz) (`eclipse-java-helios-macosx-cocoa.tar.gz`)**

---

Here are some installation tutorial (generally for 64-bit version, but can also be usefull for the 32-bit edition)

See [Installing Eclipse Galileo on Mac OS X](http://blog.zvikico.com/2009/10/installing-eclipse-galileo-on-mac-os-x.html) (can be applied to Helios)

> **Snow Leopard (10.6.x) Users**
>
> **Download the Mac Cocoa 64-Bit version.**
>
> <del>Again, the Carbon version is there in case you encounter compatibility issues with older plugins</del>.

(not anymore with Helios: no Carbon version, only Cocoa)

> The main reason you would want to use the 32-Bit version is because of plugins which are incompatible with 64-Bit.
>   This time, the 32-Bit version will waste your resources because you will cause the OS to start a whole bunch of 32-Bit services.

Read the original post for more details.

See also [Java 1.6 & Eclipse on Mac OS X](http://excitedcuriosity.wordpress.com/2009/11/16/java-1-6-eclipse-on-mac-os-x/):

> Initially, the latest version of Eclipse (3.5) was released only in 32-bit mode for bot:
>
> - Carbon (an older and deprecated Mac OS API) and
> - Cocoa (the modern Mac OS API).
>
> Since Leopard only supported Java 1.6 in 64-bit mode, this meant that Eclipse was always running under Java 1.5. With the release of Eclipse 3.5.1, there are now 64-bit Cocoa downloads available, and these will run under Java 1.6.
>
> Everyone apparently agrees that on Snow Leopard you want the 64-bit Cocoa version of Eclipse (unless you are on a 32-bit Intel Mac).

Comment: @Gr8: then try the 32-bit version and see if the problem persists

Comment: Ok. I just downloaded the 32-bit version too. Plz let me try.

Comment: I've downloaded the 32bit version of Eclipse. It is not giving that error but its also not installing. What it shows is just a slash image on clicking. =(

Comment: @Gr8: that means the eclipse.ini is somehow incorrect. See ** [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659) ** and in particular specify the full path of your JDK installation in it. Also edit your question to include the web address you used to download your eclipse (not the general download.org page, but the specific download page used to download your specific eclipse version)

Comment: Hey VonC,
    I've specified the path of JavaVM in eclipse.ini but its still not running. Any clue?

Comment: @Gr8: what is the exact download address you used? http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/R/eclipse-java-helios-macosx-cocoa.tar.gz ?

Comment: @Gr8: also try launching eclipse through a shell: `eclipse -consolelog -debug` (as in http://wiki.eclipse.org/How_to_report_a_deadlock#Using_eclipse_-consolelog or http://wiki.eclipse.org/RCP_FAQ#When_I_try_running.2C_nothing_happens.2C_or_it_complains_that_the_application_could_not_be_found_in_the_registry.2C_or_that_other_plug-ins_are_missing._How_can_I_track_the_problem_down.3F). See if there is any log produced, any telling error message.

Comment: This is the exact download add, http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/helios/R/eclipse-java-helios-macosx-cocoa.tar.gz

Comment: This command "eclipse -consolelog -debug" is generating error:

"-bash: eclipse: command not found"

What to do now? =(

Comment: AFAIK, the Core Duo is a 32 bit processor, not capable of running 64 bit at all. Even if you install Snow Leopard. First, you need the 32 bit version. Second, make sure 32 bit Java is your default. You can set it using an application called JavaPreferences, sitting in the /Applications/Utilities.

Comment: @zvikico: I've checked that my default is 32-bit Java.

Comment: @Gr8: then make sure to download and test the Macosx Cocoa 32bits (eclipse-java-helios-macosx-cocoa.tar.gz), as my updated answer mentions.

Comment: I've post my progress and my eclipse.ini file content below as an answer. Plz help!

Answer (score 0):

You probably downloaded a 32bit version although a 64bit is required or vice versa.

Comment: My team mate has downloaded Eclipse using this same dmg, he has the same OS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot for your time VonC and zvikico. You guys are awesome.

I've downloaded Macosx Cocoa 32bits (eclipse-java-helios-macosx-cocoa.tar.gz), specified path for my Java in eclipse.ini file and set up 32-bit Java using "Java Preferences".

But the issue is still unresolved.

I'm sending below the content of my eclipse.ini file (the version of my java is 1.6.0_20):

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx_1.1.0.v20100503
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vm
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/bin/java
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6.0_20
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

Comment: 2 points: 1/ the path for `startup` and `launcher.library` should be directly '`plugins`', not '`../../../plugins`': your `eclipse.ini` file should directly be within the eclipse installation directory, right along plugins and features sub-directories. 2/ `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6.0_20` seems strange to me: `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6` is better, as specified [in my `eclipse.ini`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse)

Comment: Changed version but...
After removing "../../../" eclipse is giving error "eclipse executable launcher is unable to find its companion launcher jar."

Comment: well, do you see `plugins` and `features` directory right along your `eclipse.ini`? Did you put `eclipse.ini` within the `eclipse` directory of your eclipse installation? Actually (even simpler), try to ditch those settings altogether: remove 4 lines (the `-startup` and `--launcher.library`) and see if that works. But again, the `eclipse.ini` file must be properly placed.